# Manipulating the return of data on a jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fadein

So the issue currently doesn't lie in the ajax itself, just what to do once i get the data back. Im having an immense issue in trying to have it prepend the data into a class on dynamic content. 
Here is the code that does the ajax request, again the ajax works as expected, but when i tried to prepend the data returned, it would add it to every post on my site (http://readysetfail.com).

```
                     /*
         * This is the ajax
         */
        $(".reply").on( "submit" , function(){
        // Intercept the form submission
        var formdata = $(this).serialize(); // Serialize all form data

        // Post data to your PHP processing script
        $.post( "/comment.php", formdata, function( data ) {
            // Act upon the data returned, setting it to #success <div>
            $(this).parent('.post_comment').children('.view_comments').prepend(data);
            $('.hidden').hide();
        });
           return false;
        });
        /*
         * End ajax
         */
```

Sorry if i'm explaining this awfully, just as a summary this is what i would ideally want. The user to hit Post Comment, then it fades in the comment they posted on the correct post.

Thanks a ton!

Jon

I solved it!

It was a simple solution, i stored the jquery variable like so then was able to navigate :)

```
$(".reply").on( "submit" , function(){
        // Intercept the form submission
        var formdata = $(this).serialize(); // Serialize all form data
        var reply = $(this); 

        // Post data to your PHP processing script
        $.post( "/comment.php", formdata, function( data ) {
            // Act upon the data returned, setting it to .success <div>
            reply.parent().next().prepend(data);
            $('.hidden').hide();
        });
        return false;
        });
```

Comment: it's appending to everyone because you're using class names, so every single element with the class name `reply` is going to have its parent prepended too

Comment: Instead of selecting the children of the parent, just select the first child if that's what you want to prepend it to.

Comment: Just a quick tip with jQuery, `$("#reply")` will get the **FIRST** element with the *ID* "reply", whereas `$(".reply")` will get **EVERY** element with the *CLASS NAME* "reply"

Comment: I'm sorry i should have changed it back to what it was, i meant to put it as (this) as that is what i was using i was just testing to get it to work again. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You should add some of your HTML code in order for us to solve the issue

Comment: I added the link to my site, i feel it would be easier for those to simply chrome inspect it if they needed to analyse the html. :)

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct JS? There is nothing on that page with a class of "reply" so I'm not sure how the $(".reply").on( "submit" , function() is even working.  Your form is NAMED reply, it doesn't have a class of reply...

Comment: It has a class of reply, i just checked now :P

Comment: ThulasiRam it's all on my website which i posted. The site is live but still in development. If you need specifics just ask :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the div id in some variable and use it after ajax call

e.g.

```
 $(".reply_comment").on( "submit" , function(event){

     event.preventDefault(); 
    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
     $.post( "/comment.php", formdata, function( data ) {

        $(this).parent('.view_comments').prepend(data);
        $('.hidden').hide();
    });
 });
```

Comment: I can't for whatever reason even get it to work now. It won't even prepend the comment data to anything like it was doing before with the exact same code i posted.

Comment: Can you try replacing children to -> find ! i'll update my code above. Also Please make sure that you are targetting all the selectors properly i.e. parent .post_comment contains 2 class - > .reply & .view_comments

Comment: Thanks, It didn't work, but perhaps its my .parent selector that is the issue. I'm not sure at what level jquery is selected when ajax is finished. I also have no idea how to tell.

Comment: If you have FireBug on FireFox, you can view the Error Console and see if the jQuery/JS is creating an error when running. If you are confused i suggest using parent() directy without any selector let the data get prepend in all the depending container and later using firebug / inspect element find the appropriate container.

Comment: kishan i'm trying what you are saying and i can successfully have the data prepend on all elements with ('.success').prepend(data); which has the desired effects but it does it on all the posts, the issue i am currently facing is figuring out WHERE jquery is selecting after i hit post comment, and drilling upward or downward to the correct div from there.

Comment: can you post some hierarchical view of your classes so i can figure out whats exactly is happening. Like scratching on paper and resolving all the parent / child classes would help.

Comment: hi , i was going through your posting comment code in the url you mentioned above and i  guess i found whats going wrong Urmm im updating my code can you try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".reply").on("submit" , function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var formdata = $(this).serialize();
      $.post( "/comment.php", formdata, function( data ) {
           $(this).siblings('.view_comments').prepend(data);
           $('.hidden').hide();
      });
});
```